# PSR-4 autoloading with Composer - Class not found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm create composer package with type `library`. And trying to require it to Symfony2 project.

The package has following `composer.json`

```json
{
    "name": "vendor/package-sdk",
    "description": "My private package",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Vendor\\PackageSDK\\": "src/"}
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    }
}
```

Then I require it to my SF2 project.

```json
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:me/vendor-package-sdk.git"
    },
],
"require": {
    ...
    "vendor/package-sdk": "~0.0.1-alpha1"
    ...
}
```

When I calling

```php
use Vendor\PackageSDK\Client;

...

$client = new Client();
```

```

And I got fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Vendor\PackageSDK\Client' not found in /path
```

If I do

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

It works, but

```
composer dump-autoload
```

not.

The file **vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php** contain:

```php
'Vendor\\PackageSDK\\' => array($vendorDir . '/vendor/package-sdk/src'),
```

Could anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick glance on mobile it looks like you have the wrong name call..? package **-** sdk vs packageSDK,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In composer **autoload_classmap.php** file I saw the following line

'Vendor\PackageSDK\Client' => $vendorDir . '/vendor/package-sdk/src/**Cilent**.php',

So it's just a typo in filename of package

**Cilent**.php should be **Client**.php